# When multiple versions of a class are made available by different class loaders, how can I reference a particular one?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This problem stems from the IntelliJ GUI designer, which seems to load custom form components in an environment that includes its own, older version of `MigLayout`.

If I create a custom component that uses `MigLayout`:

```
import net.miginfocom.layout.CC;
import net.miginfocom.layout.LC;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ComponentUsingMigLayout extends JPanel {
   public ComponentUsingMigLayout() {
      try {
         setLayout(new MigLayout(new LC().insets("20")));
         add(new JButton("Hello"), new CC().cell(0, 0));
      }
      catch (Throwable t) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t.toString());
      }
   }
}
```

And then create a GUI Form, do "Add Component to Palette", and select `ComponentUsingMigLayout`, I see my message dialog with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.miginfocom.layout.CC.cell([I)Lnet/miginfocom/layout/CC`.

I am guessing that this is because IntelliJ loads its own version of `MigLayout` that is made available to form components, and this is an older version that lacks the variadic `cell()` method. I know that a newer version of MigLayout should also be available to the runtime, due to a dependency on `"com.miglayout" % "miglayout-core" % "4.2"`.

Here is a [complete example including IDEA project files](https://github.com/ellbur/intellijmiglayoutexample).

Is there a way to force use of `"com.miglayout" % "miglayout-core" % "4.2"`?

Comment: If you have multiple versions and want to reference one (other than the "default") you must do it by specifying the class loader, one way or another.  One way is to explicitly do a load with that loader, to get the Class object, but that won't handle your situation, I believe.  What you need to do somehow is get your class loader to be the top one in the invocation stack -- a hair tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to detect the situation that the class is being loaded by the GUI designer, and dissect the class loader to remove the parent:

```
package guidesignermiglayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "ToArrayCallWithZeroLengthArrayArgument"})
public class ComponentUsingMigLayout extends JPanel {
   public ComponentUsingMigLayout() {
      try {
         ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();

         ClassLoader localCL;
         if (cl.getClass().getName().contains("DesignTimeClassLoader")) {
            localCL = new URLClassLoader(((List<URL>) cl.getClass().getMethod("getUrls").invoke(cl)).toArray(new URL[]{}));
         }
         else {
            localCL = cl;
         }

         Class migLayout = localCL.loadClass("net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout");

         Class lc = localCL.loadClass("net.miginfocom.layout.LC");
         Method insets = lc.getDeclaredMethod("insets", String.class);

         Class cc = localCL.loadClass("net.miginfocom.layout.CC");
         Method cell = cc.getDeclaredMethod("cell", int[].class);

         setLayout((LayoutManager) migLayout.getConstructor(lc).newInstance(
              insets.invoke(lc.newInstance(), "20")
         ));
         add(new JButton("Hello"), cell.invoke(cc.newInstance(), new Object[]{new int[]{0, 0}}));
      }
      catch (Throwable t) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t.toString());
      }
   }
}
```